# Difference between the term "Panel" and "Layout" in WPF

Tags: wpf, naming-conventions

In WPF, the term "Panel" and "Layout" both converges to the idea of a control hosting other controls, but how do they functionally differ from each other?

Take for example a custom control that displays its children content in some random order. When should the custom control name be `MyRandomDisplayPanel` and `MyRandomDisplayLayout`?

Comment: The term Layout does *not* mean a parent control like Panel. `Panel` is the base class of all WPF controls that can contain multiple child elements, and has a `Children` property to manage them.

Comment: Yes, but you "lay" controls in a "layout", for instance a Grid. In the end, a layout hosts controls

Comment: That is what it *does*, but not how it's called. You may however call your derived Panel as you wish. It doesn't really matter as long as the name is understandable.

Comment: i agree with you, but its not about code but rather the term. I am more interested in finding a good name for my custom control, like should it be xxxPanel or xxxLayout

Comment: If you actually need a suffix, you should choose `Panel`, as in `StackPanel` or `WrapPanel`. The name may however be well understandable without a suffix, like `UniformGrid`.